# How to pass table name dynamically in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to write sample procedure to count the records present in specific tables, here i will fetch the table name s from the text file.
Fo this i just write sample procedure to fetch th table names from text file and storing in tem table but while i am assigning and passing the table name i am unable to do it can any one suggest how to do it by simple example

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing you should do in T-SQL. If you want to assemble queries, you should do it in a middle-tier component.

Answer (score 2):

You can build dynamic sql using table name parameter and execte it using EXEC as shown below.

```
Create procedure Proc1
@TableName varchar(MAX)
as
..
...
DECLARE @sqltxt varchar(1000)
select @sqltxt = 'select count(*) from ' + quotename(@TableName)
exec (@sqltxt)
...
...
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, you should use `Quotename`: `Set @sqltxt = 'Select ... From ' + Quotename( @TableName )`.

Comment: exec (@sql) should be exec (@sqltxt)

Comment: +1 for the corrected version, although the actual correct answer should be "don't do this".

Comment: @Thomas - Ya.That's why I had asked a query / feature request in meta for marking a comment as an answer. If they would have enabled this feature, then your query could have been marked as answer!
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer